# QtCreator 2.3--Lost ability to see QString contents in debugger

Tags: string, qt, gdb, qt-creator, qstring

So I recently upgraded to QtCreator 2.3 (and want to keep it for its QtQuick support) and initially debugger performance slowed to an unusable crawl (though I could still see QString contents).  Googling around led me to install gdb 7.3.1, the latest stable release at this time, and that happily brought debugger stepping speed back up to usable levels.  But now the debugger won't display the contents of a QString, just the address of the char array, and a lot of private members that don't tell me anything informative.  Anybody know how I can get the debugger to display string contents again?  I'm on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: I assume you rebuilt the debugging helper (Qt4 page in the settings)?

Comment: @Frank No I had not.  But Tools -> Options -> Qt4 has 'Not Needed' next to GDB Helper in the list of helpers.  I've rebuilt everything anyway, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 2):

Check this
<strike>http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/6323</strike>

Edit: The page isn't available anymore, the domain is currently parked.

@gshep Please replace the link if you can remember the title of the page and find another instance of it.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20120204222958/http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/6323